# 3d reconstruction from 2 views

Tags: triangulation, 3d-reconstruction, structure-from-motion

I'm doing some study on the 3d reconstruction from two views and fixed known camera focal length. Something that is unclear to me is does triangulation gives us the real world scale of an object or the scale of the result is different to the actual one? If the scale is different than the actual size, how can I find the depth of points from it? I was wondering if there is more information that I need to create a real world scale of object.

Answer (score 0):

Scale is arbitrary in SfM tasks so the result may be different in every reconstruction since points are initially projected on a random depth value.

You need at least one known distance in your scene to recover the absolute (real-world) scale. You can include one object with known size in your scene so you will be able to convert your scale afterwards.